# Can I compile C# 6 for .NET 4?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

With Visual Studio 2014, can I write C# 6 code to build for .NET Framework 4? We're limited to .NET 4 by our clients, but we'd still like to use the new language features of C# 6 such as the operator `.?` and  the `nameof` keyword.

Comment: Why not just install the developer preview for VS 2014 and find out?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0