# Failing to compile Newtonsoft.Json.Net20

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, json.net

I downloaded Newtonsoft.Json code from http://www.newtonsoft.com/json and opened Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.sln in VS 2013. When I build it I get a bunch of errors, all are in JsonPrimitiveContract.cs, here is one sample

```
Invalid expression term '[' C:\Users\<path removed>\Newtonsoft.Json-master\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonPrimitiveContract.cs   60  13  Newtonsoft.Json.Net20
```

I also tried compiling Newtonsoft.Json.sln, same errors. Obviously I am missing something, just don't know what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET has a [solution](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.sln) that [*targets*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0) .Net version 2.0, but the source code must be *compiled* using the c# 6.0 compiler.  From [Issue #802](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/802):

> 06needhamt commented 6 days ago
>
> I am requesting a branch of JSON.NET that can be compiled without c#6 as my organization does not support C# 6 and need to use a source distribution due to modifications,
>
> JamesNK commented 6 days ago
>
> Nope. C# 6 or bust.
>
> Or use the source before C# 6 features.

According to your question, you are using VS 2013.  Thus you need to move to VS 2015 or try to install c# 6.0 into VS 2013.  While I've never attempted it, [How to enable C# 6.0 feature in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013) says it might be possible and explains how to do it.