# Getting "Invalid Expression Term '.' " error when compiling a C# program

Tags: c#

So currently I was tasked to run a crm solution that was written by 3rd party. I am a java dev and not so used to the c# dev environment.

I am trying to just rebuild the dll, but I keep getting `Invalid expression term '.'` at the following line:

```
investor.CustomerTypeCode = i.clientType?.code;
```

Which is to check for a nullable field apparently.

I thought it might be a .net version issue but tried everything till 4.5 .

Hope someone can maybe point me in the right direction

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: Getting a compiler error : Error 3 Invalid expression term '.'
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought it might be a .net version issue but tried everything till 4.5 .

You stopped too early: the `?.` operator has not been introduced until C# 6, which is part of .NET 4.6 release.

You can target .NET 4.5 and earlier as well, as long as you have the right compiler version (see [*Does C# 6.0 work for .NET 4.0?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28921749/335858) for more details).

If using C# 6 compiler is not an option, rewrite the assignment as follows:

```
investor.CustomerTypeCode = i.clientType != null ? i.clientType.code : null;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into the other .net version now. I did a check to see if the rewrite will work. Thank you