# Null-conditional Operators Compatibility

Tags: c#, .net

The [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) has supposedly been introduced in C# 6.0 (or .NET Framework 4.6). However, my project uses the 4.5.2 version of the framework (C# 5.0). While I'm using Visual Studio 2015, the IDE seems to understand the new notation and compiles/works properly. However, I'm confused about whether the project would still work upon publish. My development machine has 4.6 installed but the production server might not.

In other words, is the Null-conditional Operators really compatible with 4.5.2 or am I missing something?

Comment: It's part of the compiler, not the framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`C# 6` works on the `NET 4.5.1`. You don't need `.Net 4.6`.

For more see **[Does C# 6.0 work for .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0)**

Comment: Is Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 required in this case?

Comment: No it isn't required. So you need only to install the compiler