# How can I control if the tag I wanna read is in the xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I read tags for some information in the online dynamic xml file. But an error occurs  if the tag I wanna read is not in the xml file. So, I wanna check the xml file. if the tag is in the xml file, start reading xml for the tag. if the tag is not in the xml file, not reading. I am not good in  coding c#..

I use this method for reading xml file.

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load("http://yourwebsite.com/weather.xml");,

temperature.Text = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("temp").InnerXml.ToString();
windspeed.Text = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("wind_spd").InnerXml.ToString();
storm.Text = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("storm").InnerXml.ToString();
```

The storm tag is sometimes to be in the xml file. Then I can read this time.
But when the storm tag is not to be in xml file, I take an error. The code doesn't work.

Shortly, I wanna do this,

```
if(the storm tag is in xml) //check xml file.
{
 storm.Text = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("storm").InnerXml.ToString();
}
else
{
    storm.text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for node like this:

```
var node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("storm");
if (node != null)
{
    storm.Text = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("storm").InnerXml.ToString();
}
else
{
    //node doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use null propagation.
Something like:
`temperature.Text = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("temp")?.InnerXml.ToString();`
So in case of `xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("temp")` returns null - `temperature.Text` will also be null without exception.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I take a syntax error for 'InnerXml'. as "expected ':' for InnerXml".

Comment: I believe this feature is only available in new versions of the .net framework. You can change your target framework to a newer version or you can add some files to the older frameworks. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0