# how to add Single Quote before and after in a string c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

This is my code and I want single quote before and after.

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '\\' };
selectedITeration += (lis.Text.Trim(charsToTrim) + ",").Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Output:

```
    \MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\AS-Automation,
\MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\Pluse Pheonix,
\MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\Pluse Pheonix\Sprint 1,
\MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\Pluse Pheonix\Sprint 10
```

I want something like this:

```
'MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\AS-Automation',
'MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Pluse Pheonix',
'MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Pluse Pheonix\\Sprint 1',
'MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Pluse Pheonix\\Sprint 10'
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
selectedITeration +=
   String.Format("'{0}'", (lis.Text.Trim(charsToTrim) + ",").Replace(@"\", @"\\"));
```

or C# 6.0 ([string inerpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation))

```
selectedITeration += $"'{(lis.Text.Trim(charsToTrim) + ",").Replace(@"\", @"\\")}'";
```

Just for FYI : [Does C# 6.0 work for .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921701/does-c-sharp-6-0-work-for-net-4-0)

Comment: String interpolation doesn't depend on the .NET Framework - but on the version of the C# compiler - has to be v6 or higher

Comment: @marc_s - updated and thanks , i thought better to put framework , most of the people got confuse with C# version and framework version , yes it language feature

Comment: could u modify ur answer i have changed Question little bit (not needed the iteration now)  @PranayRana

Comment: @nikhiljain - dont see any update in question ...and not getting you at all ...no iteration means you have long string ??

Comment: @nikhiljain - what is change in it , i see same , and not much detail

Comment: don't want the Iteration part \MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Iteration\\Pluse Pheonix\Sprint 10 should become MRI_SCRUM_GIT\\Pluse Pheonix\\Sprint 10   @PranayRana

Comment: @PranayRana got it boss ?

Comment: @nikhiljain - remove iteration just do` (lis.Text.Trim(charsToTrim) + ",").Replace("Iteration\\","").Replace(@"\", @"\\")`

Answer (score 1):

What is so difficult in that:

```
selectedITeration += ("'" + lis.Text.Trim(charsToTrim) + "',").Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Comment: could u modify ur answer i have changed Question little bit (not needed the iteration now)